# jQuery find location of next row to add Quick View

Tags: jquery

I have a collection of 'li' products in a grid view, with a dynamic variable that sets the number of products per row. What I am trying to do is find the location of the last item in the row and append a 'Quick View' div below it and push down the row beneath it.

So if items per row is set to 4 and you were to click on item 1,2,3,4 of the first row you should get something like this:

```
<li class="post-1"></li>
<li class="post-2"></li>
<li class="post-3"></li>
<li class="post-4"></li>

<div class="quick-view">I am placed here because either item 1,2,3 or 4 were clicked</div>

<li class="post-5"></li>
<li class="post-6"></li>

<div class="quick-view">I would be placed here if the items per row was set to 6 because either item 1,2,3,4,5,6 were clicked</div>

<li class="post-7"></li>
<li class="post-8"></li>
<li class="post-9"></li>
<li class="post-10"></li>
<li class="post-11"></li>
<li class="post-12"></li>
```

So I am having some trouble with the math or logic of the problem how do you figure, based on the items per row variable, where the end of the row is.

some basic code not sure if useful

```
var post = $('.post-' + post_id);
var loc = post.index();
var items_per_row = product_quick_view_vars.items_per_row;
```

Comment: Note that a `<div>` is, in no way whatsoever, a valid child of a `<ul>` element; only the humble `<li>` is a valid child of the `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the li items are always a multitude of the `items_per_row`, you can simple get the index to add to by `flooring` or `ceil`ing the division with items_per_row and multiplying it again with items_per_row to get the index.

For example: `var indextoadd = items_per_row * Math.ceil(++itemindex / items_per_row);`

A test scenario: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2x35jrsr/)
Test code:

```
var items = $('li');

$('li').click(function(e){
    var items_per_row = 4; // product_quick_view_vars.items_per_row;

    var item = $(e.target); //the li that was clicked
    var itemindex = items.index(item); //find the li index
    var indextoadd = items_per_row * Math.ceil(++itemindex / items_per_row) - 1; //determine the item after which to append (-1 to get the 0 based index)

    var div = $('<div class=newdiv>A new div</div>'); //create a new div (class is just as an example)

    $(items[indextoadd]).after(div);
});
```

Comment: That's great exactly what I needed, thanks for the help